# Escape Character for SQL in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to add a simple select statement in my C# code. Sample looks like below.  The value like y in fname comes from a parameter.
    //select lname from myTable where fname = 'y'

Here's what I m doing. I m obviously getting Sql Exception. How do I correct it? Thanks.

```
string strOrdersOrigSQL = "SELECT LastName FROM Employees";
// Concatenate the default SQL statement with the "Where" clause and add an OrderBy clause
       strOrdersSQL = strOrdersOrigSQL + "where FirstName ="+ 'strFname';
```

Comment: use sql parameters with sqlcommand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But it can be done as

```
string strOrdersOrigSQL = "SELECT LastName FROM Employees";
// Concatenate the default SQL statement with the "Where" clause and add an OrderBy clause
       strOrdersSQL = strOrdersOrigSQL + " where FirstName ='"+ strFname + "'";
```

This is not proper way of doing it since it can be affected by SQL Injection. Use parameterised queries instead.

Answer (score 15):

You should never concat sql commands by hand. Use the class [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) and add parameters

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT LastName FROM Employees where FirstName = @firstName", conn))
{
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", strFname);
   var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Comment: I think it should be ExecuteScalar or ExecuteReader

Comment: It petrifies me that people still do this.

Answer (score 3):

Some other problems with your query are that you are missing a space and the quotes go inside the string literal:

```
strOrdersSQL = strOrdersOrigSQL + " where FirstName = '"+ strFname + "'";
//                                 ^                  ^               ^
```

But this still won't work if the variable contains a quote character or backslash.

Instead of trying to escape the string you should use **parameterized queries**.

Answer (score 3):

You dont need to worry about escaping charaters in Sql when passing from C#

Sql does it for you

all you need to do si:

```
string strOrdersOrigSQL = "SELECT LastName FROM Employees Where  FirstName = @FirstName"
```

Nwo you can pass the value for @FirstName via SqlParameter this will protect you query from Sql injection

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use SqlCommand. But if you choose to write direct SQL, it is OK as long as you escape your input. You should be very careful with this and know what you are doing. Else, your code presents an [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Here is the correct code:

```
string strOrdersOrigSQL = "SELECT LastName FROM Employees ";
// Concatenate the default SQL statement with the "Where" clause and add an OrderBy clause
strOrdersSQL = strOrdersOrigSQL + "where FirstName = '" + strFname.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
```

Assuming that strFname is a variable.

Comment: yup, and as a user the first thing I would do is put in my name as "'; delete from employees;" :)

Comment: I would use "; TRUNCATE TABLE EMPLOYEES;" :P no logging and fast